# Calling MVC Controller Action return 404

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, devextreme

I am begginer at ASP .NET Core and I got a problem, which I am not able to fix. I have simple file uploading web page, with some Web API behind. In VS2019 everything works properly, but when I Publish it on my test IIS server, I got 404 with calling some Controllers Actions. Basic redirection works OK.

I have simple form with DevExtreme file uploader, which call my FileUploaderController and his action Upload on FormSubmit (made with btn click). This works OK in VS2019, but return 404 when published on IIS. It does not log any error which I could analyse.

Here is my Startup.cs setup:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddMvcOptions(options =>
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        services.AddControllers();
        services
            .AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
        

        // registrace konfigurace
        services.Configure<ApplicationConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationConfiguration"));

        // registrace závislostí
        DependencyRegistrator.RegisterDependecies(services);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Index.cshtml :

```
@using (Html.DevExtreme().ValidationGroup())
{
    <div class="input-box">
        <div class="dx-field">
            <div class="dx-field-label">Odesílatel (email): </div>
            <div class="dx-field-value">
                @* Kontrolky kterým můžu určit proměnnou v modelu, mají za jménem "For"
                    V hlavičce kontrolky se da určit kam v modelu patří *@
                @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBoxFor(m => m.Sender)
                    .Placeholder("Odesílatel (email)")
                    .Name("Sender")
                 )
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dx-field">
            <div class="dx-field-label">Příjemce (email): </div>
            <div class="dx-field-value">
                @* Kontrolky kterým můžu určit proměnnou v modelu, mají za jménem "For"
                    V hlavičce kontrolky se da určit kam v modelu patří *@
                @*@(Html.DevExtreme().TextBoxFor(m => m.Receiver)
                       .Placeholder("Příjemce (email)")
                       .Name("Receiver")
                    )*@
                @(Html.DevExtreme().TagBoxFor(m => m.Receivers)
                      .Name("Receivers")
                      .Placeholder("Příjemci (email adresy)")
                      .DataSource(new string[] { })
                      .AcceptCustomValue(true)
                      .OpenOnFieldClick(false)
                      .OnCustomItemCreating("onCustomItemCreating")
                      .DisplayExpr("value")
                )
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dx-field">
            <div class="dx-field-label">Poznámky: </div>
            <div class="dx-field-value">
                @* Kontrolky kterým můžu určit proměnnou v modelu, mají za jménem "For"
                    V hlavičce kontrolky se da určit kam v modelu patří *@
                @(Html.DevExtreme().TextAreaFor(m => m.Notes)
                    .Height(150)
                    .Name("Notes")
                )
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="fileuploader">
            <div class="widget-container">
                @* FileUploader se v modelu přiřazuje podle jména kontrolky, musí mít "Name" stejný, jako je proměnná v modelu *@
                @(Html.DevExtreme().FileUploader()
                    .SelectButtonText("Vyberte soubor")
                    .LabelText("nebo přesuňte sem")
                    .ID("file-uploader")
                    .Name("MyFiles")  @* <------- Tady se přiřadí k proměnné v modelu *@
                    .Accept("*")
                    .Multiple(true)
                    .MaxFileSize(Config.Value.MaxFileSize)
                    .UploadMode(FileUploadMode.UseForm)
                    .UploadMethod(UploadHttpMethod.POST)
                )
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="upload-button">
            @* Protože je tohle tlačítko ve formuláři, jeho stiskntí postne celý formulář *@
            @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
                .ID("UploadButton")
                .Text("UploadFiles")
                .Type(ButtonType.Success)
                .UseSubmitBehavior(true)
                .Disabled(true)
            )
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And FileUploaderController:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("FileUploader")]
public class FileUploaderController : Controller
{
    // private properties and constructor
   
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Upload")]
    public IActionResult Upload([FromForm]FileShareOrder fileShareOrder)
    {
        Logger.Information("Přijatá zásilka.");

        bool processSucces = UploadProcesser.TryUploadOrder(fileShareOrder);
        
        var view = View("../Home/Index");

        view.TempData["Succes"] = processSucces;
        view.TempData["Fail"] = !processSucces;

        return view;
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me, as my google research did not.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Solved, I was just stupid and made a mistake in DB connection string, which resolved into SqlException. I did not noticed it and was to focused on 404 error instead of looking for error elsevere.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this route attribute

```
    [Route("~/FileUploader/Upload")]
    public IActionResult Upload([FromForm]FileShareOrder fileShareOrder)
```

And change

```
View("../Home/Index");
```

To

```
View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This route attribute has same results, works in VS2019 but not at published IIS.

Comment: Pls show the URL that  is not found at IIS.

Comment: http://myserver.cz/UschovnaTest/FileUploader/Upload is not found

http://myserver.cz/UschovnaTest/Admin/OrdersOverview is found 

I cant see any diference, only that UploadController/Upload return index view, Can there possibly be error in Index view found in Upload Action?

"var view = View("../Home/Index");"

Comment: Yes, you have to change view path according to my answer.